# node.js + mysql Query from url

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I am new to this node.js. I am using mysql in my node.js. From the url i am constructing sql query. With 1 parameter its working fine.

The URL:

```
http://ipaddress:3002/users/Kappalur
```

By using the following code i extracted the Kappalur and its working fine:

```
app.get('/users/:level', function (req, res) {

connection.query("select * from levels where level4= '"+req.params.level+"'", function(err, rows, fields) {
res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
            res.end(JSON.stringify(rows,null,"\n"));

Now my requirement is i want to make "level4" to be dynamic..
```

Consider now the url be:

```
 http://ipaddress:3002/users/level4/Kappalur
```

Now how can i change the above code to get the 2 parameters from url. Help me to solve this..Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood you are using `express` framework for node.js.

To retrieve multiple URL parameters use just the same pattern as that you have used in your post's code snippet:

```
app.get('/users/:level/:name', function (req, res) {
    var level = req.params.level;
    var name = req.params.name;
```

Comment: @Subburaj Try this `"select * from levels where " + req.params.level  + " = '" + req.params.name + "'"` (assuming the 2nd parameter is name)

Comment: @Subburaj Yes, your mistake was in SQL syntax. It must be `select * from levels where level4 = 'Kappalur'` instead of `select * from levels where 'level4' = 'Kappalur'`

Comment: `level4` can not be int since you use it as column name. Then something wrong is with how you construct your SQL query.

Comment: As `var columnname = "level" + req.params.level`

Comment: My question is that when i retrieve result consider i have 5 fileds in my table  field1 field2 field3 field4 field5..Based on field5 i have to execute another query..So whether its possible to know the value of filed5 before forming json,y because as i said i have to execute another query ,that query results should be used to form the json..

Comment: May be you can use subquery?

Comment: I am very new to this web development side..node.js + my sql..Can you give me a path to acheive this..

Comment: Unfortunately your intents are little bit unclear for me. Subqueries allow you to use results of one query in the other one, for example, `SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE column1 = (SELECT column1 FROM t2);`